# Ruby: Comparison Operator as a string

Tags: ruby, operators

I am working on a Rails app that allows a user to check off tasks as they have completed them and I am working on a method that will return past due tasks and upcoming tasks.

Here is my method in my User model:

```
  def task_notification(notification_type = "past")
    return false if tasks.empty?

    current_month = Time.now.month
    tasks.where(classification: classification).select { |task| task.due_date < current_month }
  end
```

I am basically trying to do something like this:

```
operator = notification_type.eql?("past") ? "<" : ">"
tasks.where(classification: classification).select { |task| task.due_date operator current_month }
```

obviously the above doesn't work, I am just wondering how to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-send)

```
task.due_date.send(operator, current_month)
```

Comment: Let me give that a try!! Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `operator.to_sym` ?

Comment: @steenslag: `Object#send` is clever enough to do that on its own.